# Is it possible to call super to invoke alias method in a method that is being aliased

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say in the activerecord model car there are two boolean fields: suv and blue

If there is a method in the car model defined as such

```
  def suv
   something_true? ? super : false
  end
  alias :blue :suv
```

Now if something_true? is true, the "super" works if i invoke car.suv. However, it does not work if i invoke car.blue, then the car.blue instead returns the value of suv stored in the database.  Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using `alias_method` instead of `alias`? [This article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html) discusses some of the differences. Also, you have an extra `?` in your ternary operator.

Comment: Right I did try using alias_method. I'll fix the extra "?" thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a clever idea but I don't think it will work. Even if it's accessed through an alias, calling `super` inside the method `suv` will only call `suv`. You can use metaprogramming though:

```
class A
  def a; 1; end
  def b; 2; end
end

class B < A
  def initialize(condition)
    @condition = condition
  end
  %i{a b}.each do |fn|
    define_method(fn) do
      @condition ? super() : "default"
    end
  end
end

puts B.new(false).a # => "default"
puts B.new(false).b # => "default"
puts B.new(true).a  # => 1
puts B.new(true).b  # => 2
```